# What's wrong with my do while loop in C++?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I'm supposed to use a do while loop to display when Mexico's population exceeds the US population, starting from 1985, whenever I run my program it says that the part that says "Years++" is wrong. Here's my code:

//Program to compute when Mexico's pop exceeds the US pop

```
#include<iostream>
##include<cmath>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int Years;
double UsPop, MxPop;
cout<<setw(7)<<"Year"<<setw(13)<<"US Pop"<<setw(13)<<"Mex Pop"<<endl;
cout<<setprecision(0)<<fixed;
Years=1985;
do
{
    UsPop=243000000.0*(pow(1.007,(Years-1984)));
    MxPop=78000000*(pow(1.033,(Years-1984)));
    cout<<setw(7)<<Years<<setw(13)<<UsPop<<setw(13)<<MxPop<<endl;
}
Years++;
while(UsPop>MxPop);
}
```

Comment: You need to put the `Years++` line inside the do while loop.

Comment: Your `Years++` seems to have found its way between the `do` block and the `while`.

Answer (score 0):

`Years++` is outside the `}` that closes the loop.